# Destroy event not propagating from Backbone model to Backbone collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a backbone collection of models.

```
MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: myMymodel;
});

MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
...
});
```

Each model has a view

```
myView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.model = new MyModel();
  };
});
```

There is no persistence on the server-side.  This is just for structuring client-side information.  So the models do not have ids, and a url for Backbone.sync has not been configured.

From within the view, I want to remove the model from the collection.

I have tried the following:

```
this.model.trigger( "destroy" );
```

However it does not work.  The destroy event is not propagating to the collection.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Probably you would need the collection to sync again with the models.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not instantiating the collection at all. Cant make out that from the code at least. If you are just creating a model instance but not adding it to any collection, `this.model.trigger("destroy");` will do nothing.

```
myView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.coll = new MyCollection();
    this.model = new MyModel();
    this.coll.add(this.model);
  };
});
```

Now that the model is part of the collection:

```
this.model.destroy()
```

Makes a delete api call and gets removed from the collection

```
this.collection.remove(this.model)
```

Removes the model from the collection but does not make a delete api call.

```
this.model.trigger("destroy");
```

Triggers a destroy event on the model but does not destroy the model as such. sames as `collection.remove(this.model)` if model is part of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

`collection.remove(model)` would be a more appropriate function to use since you're not persisting your models on the server-side. [Backbone.Collection.remove](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-remove)